# Drop rows on multiple conditions (based on 2 column) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, lambda

I have a pandas data frame with 2 million records. (2 columns such as DA1 and DA2)
If I sort the data frame base on DA1 value, it looks like below. My real data frame has 2 million records.

```
df
    DA1   DA2
0   1.0   1.0
1   1.0   11256.0
2   1.0   131248.0
3   2.0   2.0
4   2.0   11585.0
5   2.0   25894.0
6   3.0   3.0
```

If I sort the data frame base on DA2 value, it looks like below.

```
df.head(6)
        DA1         DA2
0       1.0         1.0
87472   11256.0     1.0
267142  131248.0    1.0
3       2.0         2.0
568875  11585.5     2.0
598253  25894.0     2.0
652875  365845.0    2.0
```

**If any row is flipping and has it in another row I want to drop that row. I mean if DA1 2.0 and DA2 365845.0 and another row DA1 365845.0 and DA2  2.0 I want to drop one of that.**

I basically want to drop those repeat values in indexes 87472, 267142, 568875, and 598253.
below rows basically want to drop.

```
        DA1         DA2
87472   11256.0     1.0
267142  131248.0    1.0
568875  11585.5     2.0
598253  25894.0     2.0
```

Can I do that in a for loop or lambda function?
**Most of them confuse with the above data frame. Here it's what I really want to do with a simple example. If any row flips and have the same values I want to drop that. DA1 1 and DA2 2 another row DA1 2 and DA2 1 I want to drop that.  **.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Column1":[1, 1,1, 3,2],
                    "Column2":[1,2,3,1,1]})

df
    Column1     Column2
0       1           1
1       1           2
2       1           3
3       3           1
4       2           1

# I basically need to delete 3, 4 indexes since those values already in 1,2 indexes
I need this data frame
df
    Column1     Column2
0       1           1
1       1           2
2       1           3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is index 652875 kept?

Comment: These are only indexes you want to drop? on you want to drop more.

Comment: @DavidErickson because it wasn't in 2.0 365845.0 formats. If any row is flipping and has it in another row I want to drop that row. I mean if  2.0 365845.0 and 365845.0 2.0 I want to drop one.

Comment: @Grayrigel There are lots of duplicates So many indexes I want to drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will require some engineering to find the duplicated rows considering the combination of the two columns. You can create a `Series` object to show you the duplicated rows:

```
key=df.apply(lambda x: '{}-{}'.format(min(x), max(x)), axis=1)
```

This will basically create a key for each row with the ordered values in each column separated by a dash. Then you can use this key to remove the duplicated rows:

```
df[~key.duplicated()]
```

Example:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [2, 1, 4, 3, 5]})
>>> df

Output: 

   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  1
2  3  4
3  4  3
4  5  5

>>> key=df.apply(lambda x: '{}-{}'.format(min(x), max(x)), axis=1)
>>> key

Output:

0    1-2
1    1-2
2    3-4
3    3-4
4    5-5
dtype: object

>>> df[~key.duplicated()]

Output:

   a  b
0  1  2
2  3  4
4  5  5
```

Answer (score 1):

After your sort

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('DA2')
```

Comment: but it's going to drop index- 652875  365845.0    2.0. I want to keep this row. Is there any advise?